# Stop Multiple WebAPI requests from Azure Scheduler

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I have a web api which does a task and it currently takes couple of minutes based on the data. This can increases over time.

I have Azure scheduler job which calls this web api every 10 minutes. I want to avoid the case where the second call after 10 minutes overlaps with the first call because of the increase in time for execution. How can I put the smarts in the web api so that I detect and avoid the second call if the first call is running.

Can I use AutoResetEvent or lock statements? Or keeping a storage flag to indicate busy/free a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Azure Scheduler has a 30 seconds timeout. So we cannot have a long running task called by a scheduler. The overlap of 2 subsequent calls is out of question.

Also it seems like having a long running task from a WebAPI is a bad design, because the recycling of app pools. I ended up using Azure service bus. When a task is requested message is posted to the queue. That way the time occupied by the webapi is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent state is best managed via storage. Can your long-running activity persist through a role reset (after all, a role may be reset at any time as long as availability constraints are met).

Ensure that you think through scenarios where your long running job terminates halfway through.